# Scala extract value from Future[Seq[T]] into Future[T]

Tags: scala, future

For a given `Seq` *wrapped* in a `Future`, namely for instance

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val xs = Future { Seq(1,2,3) }
```

how to extract the first (one only) value in the collection into another `Future`, namely

```
Future { 1 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val xs = Future { Seq(1,2,3) }
val x = xs.map(_.head)
```

`x` will be another `Future`, and `xs` is still usable, so you can do anything with it.